# ImageView not displaying Bitmap on real device

Tags: android

I get an Bitmap from internal storage or from the internet. When I try to display it in a ImageView, it works on different Emulator versions but not on my Galaxy S I9000. The Bitmap simply doesn't show up.

```
protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap bmp) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (bmp != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `bmp` is `null`. Check your logcat for errors.

Comment: bmp is not null and there are no logcat errors.

Comment: What happens if you comment out null check for bmp?

Comment: Well, when I comment out the null-check for bmp, nothing happens. I have no problem with getting the bmp.

Comment: I studied my Logcat and when I try to load the bmp there is a warning: `Bitmap too large to be uploaded into resource`. Maybe this is the key.

Comment: Got it now. When I resize the image to a maximum of 2048x2048 everything works!

Answer (score 3):

This is highly likely to be an underlying issue with openGL not accepting textures larger than 2400x2400. It doesn't cause crashes, but fails by not displaying the Bitmap in an ImageView.

You should always ensure that the Bitmap is smaller than 2400 in both dimensions and resize it before setting it on your view if it is larger.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to help me in displaying the image

```
public static Drawable ToDrawable(Resources r, byte[] encodedString) 
    {
        if (encodedString == null)
            return null;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodedString, 0, encodedString.length);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(r, bmp);
        // bmp.recycle();
        return drawable;

    }
```